# href not responding in a tag when toggleclass

Tags: javascript, html, css

href not working
in my template code there account setting pics when clicked it shows logout as follows

```html
<div class="user-setting">
    <a href="#" title=""><i class="ti-power-off"></i>log out</a>
</div>
```

js file

```js
$('.user-img').on('click', function () {
    $('.user-setting').toggleClass("active");
    return false;
});
```

css file

```css
.user-setting.active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.user-setting {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
    text-align: left;
    top: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: initial;
    border: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
}
```

Comment: *"Returning false from an event handler will automatically call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault()."* https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler

Answer (score 1):

[epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) provided the answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72959242/href-not-responding-in-a-tag-when-toggleclass/72959270#comment128864233_72959242):

> "*Returning false from an event handler will automatically call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault().*" [api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler)